# ArcGis 4.8 Javascript: Hover effect on map state boundaries

Tags: javascript, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I'm creating Map with All USA state boundaries and want to show highlight state when hover over any state. ArcGis provide us hover highlight feature but it seems sometimes not working correctly and also not interactive. Below is the code which I'm using:-

```
<script>
    var dojoConfig = {
      has: {
        "esri-featurelayer-webgl": 1
      }
    }
  </script>
<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.8/"></script>
<script>
    require([
          "esri/Map",
          "esri/views/MapView",
          "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
          "dojo/domReady!"
        ], function(
          Map, MapView, FeatureLayer
        ) {


        var povLayer = new FeatureLayer({
            url: "https://services.arcgis.com/P3ePLMYs2RVChkJx/arcgis/rest/services/USA_States_Generalized/FeatureServer/0",
            outFields: ["*"],
            labelingInfo: {
                symbol: {
                  type: "text",
                  color: "black",
                  haloColor: "black",
                  font: {
                    family: "sans-serif",
                    size: 8,
                    weight: "bold"
                  }
                },
                labelPlacement: "above-center",
                labelExpressionInfo: {
                  expression: "$feature.STATE_ABBR"
                }
            },
            renderer: {
                type: "simple",
                symbol: {
                    type: "simple-fill",
                    color: "hsla(282, 31%, 67%, 0.1)",
                    outline: {
                        color: [251,164,93,255],
                        width: 0.75,
                        type: "esriSLS",
                        style: "esriSLSSolid"
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        var map = new Map({
            basemap: "dark-gray",
            layers: [povLayer]
        });

        var view = new MapView({
            container: "viewDiv",
            map: map,
            center: [-99.244309, 40.004476],
            zoom: 5
        });

        view.when(function() {
          povLayer.when(function() {
            var renderer = povLayer.renderer.clone();
            renderer.type = "unique-value";
            renderer.field = "state_name";
            renderer.symbol.width = 1;
            renderer.symbol.color = [128, 128, 128, 0.8];
            renderer.symbol.cap = "round";
            povLayer.renderer = renderer;
          });
        });

        let highlight = null;
        view.whenLayerView(povLayer).then(function(layerView) {
            view.on('pointer-move', (event) => {
                view.hitTest(event)
                    .then((res) => {

                        // remove the previous highlight
                        if (highlight) {
                            highlight.remove();
                            highlight = null;
                        }
                        if (res.results.length) {

                            var feature = res.results.filter((result) => {
                                return result.graphic.layer === povLayer;
                            })[0].graphic;
                            feature.popupTemplate = povLayer.popupTemplate;
                            id = feature.attributes.FID;
                            highlight = layerView.highlight([id]);
                        }

                    });
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

After this I'm getting highlight feature like this
[image]

Is there any other way how I can show some interactive hover effect?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mapView's [highlightOptions](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-MapView.html#highlightOptions) to change the highlight effect.
Check out [this example](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/sandbox/index.html?sample=view-hittest) for more interaction options.